# Porting WPF controls to Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, porting, syncfusion

I'd like to port one of Syncfusion's (a third-party .NET controls vendor) WPF controls to Silverlight.

I understand that Silverlight is a subset of WPF and thus there will be limitations and restrictions when porting over. Has anybody done this before (with third party libraries)? Do I need to look into the source code and see what I can change, or is there a better, quicker way to do this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: A better, quicker way would be to legally buy the Silverlight version :)

Comment: I actually have the Silverlight tools, but they do not include the control that I want :(

Comment: Have you checked the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex? Usage samples [here](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html). Probably a long shot, but maybe what you are looking for is implemented in that toolkit?

Comment: Didn't know about this previously, it looks good! I'm looking at Syncfusion's Report Designer though..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use the Silverlight controls provided by SyncFusion; in case it's not available then it's going to be very tough to port a third party WPF control into SilverLight, it's obvious from the fact that 3'rd party itself is not providing that control.

You will definitely have to look into the source code and port that into SilverLight, but beware of licensing and legal things.

If you can provide details about control you want to port someone might be able to provide you an alternate solution(open source or 3'rd party) for this, that will be the easiest solution for you.

In case you decide to port the control these links will be useful -

> Porting from WPF to Silverlight: The Missing Pieces - [Part 1](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/09/23/porting-from-wpf-to-silverlight-the-missing-pieces-part-1.aspx),
> [Part 2](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/09/21/porting-from-wpf-to-silverlight-the-missing-pieces-part-2.aspx)
>
> [WPF Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903925%28VS.95%29.aspx)
>
> [Programmatic DifferencesBetween Silverlight and WPF - A Whitepaper by Wintellect, LLC](http://www.scribd.com/doc/42289894/Microsoft-WPF-Silverlight-Comparison-Whitepaper-v1-1)
>
> [XAML Processing Differences Between Silverlight Versions and WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917841%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Hey! these are useful. I'll check them out when trying